# SwiftUI: Retain search term in search bar view after view being hidden and restored

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have the below search bar in the top portion of the main view of my app.  It is used to to get a search string to perform a php service call to get a some JSON data.

```
struct SearchBarView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cd: ContentData
    @ObservedObject var lm: LocationManager
    
    @State var search: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                TextField("Search for dining location", text: $search, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
                }, onCommit: {
                    // perform actions
                }).foregroundColor(.primary)
                Button(action: {
                    self.search = ""
                    cd.searchPerfromed = false
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").opacity(search == "" ? 0 : 1)
                }
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
        }
        .padding(.top)
    }
}
```

The bottom part of the view uses buttons to switch back and forth between two views, one shows the search results and one contains favorites.  When I go to the favorites view I want the search bar to go away since it is not needed and to provide more onscreen space, but I want it to come back if I switch back to the results view.  Currently I dismiss and return the search bar view with the below code (the favorites view is 1).

```
if cd.index == 0 {
    SearchBarView(cd: self.cd, lm:self.lm)
}
```

If the search bar had a searched term in it from a performed search and it is dismissed, when it is brought back the search term is not in the search bar anymore.  It still exists since the results are still in the results view.  How do I get the search bar to show the searched term in the search bar again once it is brought back?  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to maintain the state of your search at least one level higher up (like an `ObservableObject` owned by the parent view, for example).

Then, instead of a `@State` var for `search`, you could either pass in the entire `ObservableObject`, or you could just pass a @Binding to the search term.

```
class SearchModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var search = ""
} 

//in parent:
@StateObject var searchModel = SearchModel()

if cd.index == 0 {
    SearchBarView(cd: self.cd, lm:self.lm, search: $searchModel.search)
}
```

```
struct SearchBarView: View {
    @ObservedObject var cd: ContentData
    @ObservedObject var lm: LocationManager
    
    @Binding var search: String
    //OR
    @ObservedObject var searchModel: SearchModel

    //...
```